# Search icon replaced by non functional overflow on searchview collapse

Tags: java, android, searchview

I have implemented an in-app search functionality. It works quit well when i keep orientation fixed. However if after entering my query I change orientation collapse the searchview then I get the overflow icon in place of my search icon which is again fixed when orientation is changed. Also the overflow icon does not show search option when clicked.

[keeping orientation fixed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZODg.jpg)

[changing orientation after entering query.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fqjv2.jpg)

This is my menu xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <item android:id="@+id/search"
            android:title="@string/search_title"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
   </menu>
```

This is my fragment onCreateOptionsMenu

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);
        searchString = getActivity().getPreferences(0).getString("searchString", null);
        final MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        searchView.setQueryHint(getResources().getString(R.string.search_hint));

        //set listener on search view to fire searchResultHandlerFrag
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                Fragment fragment = new SearchHandlerFrag();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("query", query);
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                searchView.clearFocus();
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.mainContainer, fragment).commit();
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        //repopulate search view with existing search string, if any
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(searchString)) {
            if(!searchMenuItem.isActionViewExpanded())
                searchMenuItem.expandActionView();
            searchView.setQuery(searchString, false);
            searchView.clearFocus();
        }

        //trying to fix the overflow problem
        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchMenuItem, new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                searchView.setIconified(true);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it feels great to answer my own question. The trick was to change the `app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"` to `app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"`.Thanks Signo.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, in your xml definition change:

```
app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
```

with:

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

It should always keep your search icon visible instead of showing the `collapseActionView` icon.

Comment: I tried that already. However it removes the back button on actionbar and also does not look nice in landscape mode.